# jQuery Chosen : How to get array of selected options text from a multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-chosen

I'm using [jQuery Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and I need to put every option **text** in an array from a multiple select's dropdown.

I can easily get all values in an array with this:

```
    <select id="select_custom" data-placeholder="Choose a city" style="width:50%;" class="chosen-processed" multiple>
      <option value="cty01">New York</option>
      <option value="cty02">Madrid</option>
      <option value="cty03">Montreal</option>
      <option value="cty04">Paris</option>
      <option value="cty05">Berlin</option>
    </select>

   var select_custom = jQuery("#select_custom");

   select_custom.change(function(){
    var values = select_custom.chosen().val();
   });
```

And depending on what option is selected, it will return an array of **values** like this:

```
    ['cty01', 'cty03', 'cty04']
```

What would be the equivalent of this to get the **text** instead of the value?

```
    ['New York', 'Montreal', 'Paris']
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `$("#select_custom option[value='cty01']").text()` create loop for all value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var select_custom = jQuery("#select_custom");

select_custom.change(function(){
  var values = select_custom.chosen().val();

  var labels = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var label = select_custom.find('option[value="'+values[i]+'"]').text();
    labels.push(label);
  }

  console.log(labels);

});
```

We're basically looping through each of the values, searching the `<select>` field for `<option>` tags matching the value and then pushing it to the `labels` array.

Comment: I get this error on my first select: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [option value="cty03"]

Comment: With this correction it's working: var label = select_custom.find('option[value="'+values[i]+'"]').text();

Comment: @Dali sorry, didn’t notice the typo. Have updated my answer. Glad you figured out what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

```js
$("#select_custom").change(function() {
  var text = $(this).find('option:selected').toArray().map(item => item.text).join();
  console.clear();
  console.log(text);
  $("#result").text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_custom" data-placeholder="Choose a city" style="width:50%;" class="chosen-processed" multiple>
      <option value="cty01">New York</option>
      <option value="cty02">Madrid</option>
      <option value="cty03">Montreal</option>
      <option value="cty04">Paris</option>
      <option value="cty05">Berlin</option>
    </select>
    
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think 'option:selected' will work with Chosen.

Comment: Did you tried ? @Dali

Comment: Yes it gives me a string like this: MadridMontrealParisBerlin

Comment: You can try Chosen Multiple Select here: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ you will see that there is no Selected if you inspect.

Comment: But I see now that there is a 'class="result-selected', maybe I can use that...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var select_custom = jQuery("#select_custom");
var arr = [];

select_custom.change(function(){
  var text = $('#select_custom option:selected').text();
  if(!arr.includes(text)) {
    arr.push(text);
  }
  console.log(arr);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="select_custom" data-placeholder="Choose a city" style="width:50%;" class="chosen-processed" multiple>
    <option value="cty01">New York</option>
    <option value="cty02">Madrid</option>
    <option value="cty03">Montreal</option>
    <option value="cty04">Paris</option>
    <option value="cty05">Berlin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hello, I need an array of texts, not values

Comment: @Dali as you can see the code you have the text not the values, so to be clear you want to push all the text options when you change the select or you want to push te text of option which is selected ?

Comment: oh sorry, I can see that now. I will try this. (I want to push the text of options selected only)

Comment: @Dali okay then I'm changing my code just a minute

Comment: @Dali the code its done.

Comment: I don't think option:selected will work with Chosen

Comment: It gives me an array but with only one key: ['MadridMontrealParisBerlin']